# Save unlimited matrix from cell arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, matrix, cell-array

I get a cell array which contains 103 cells of different dimensions. Each cell of my cell array represents a matrix and it can be displayed as an image. How can I extract each cell (ie each matrix) in a for loop?

I know how to do that one by one but not for the whole cell :

```
image1 = cellArray{1}; % extract matrix 1 (on 103) from the cell array #1
image2 = cellArray{2}; % and so on
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: What do you want to do with the extracted images? It is a very bad idea to extract them each into their own separate matrices. People might give you solutions using `eval`, but **do not** be tempted to go that route. Rather explain your end goals to us so we can suggest a smarter solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, I want to process a snake algorithm (active contour) on each image (each matrix or each image represents one of the hundred features I want to extract from a raster image).

Comment: And what form / datatype would the output of running said algorithm on a single image take?

Comment: The final goal is to obtain morphometry of each feature (perimeter, area, major axis, minor axis, excentricity). However, I can process snake algorithm on the whole raster image. I have to repeat it for each feature.

Comment: What is important is will your outputs always have the same dimensions for any image?

Comment: Not really because dimensions change when my feature is closed to the boundary of the image. My problem is I can't call directly the cell array from the snake algorithm. I have to convert this cell array into 103 matrix and then, I can call it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to loop through your cell array and apply to same function to every cell is to use `cellfun`. If your function returns a scalar e.g.

```
f = @(x)max(:)
```

then it's as simple as

```
cellfun(f, cellArray)
```

Note that `f` above is an anonymous function (or rather a function handle to an anonymous function), but more likely your function will be in its own m-file in which case you need to use the `@` operator:

```
cellfun(@f, cellArray)
```

Lastly, if your output is not a scalar then call

```
cellfun(@f, cellArray, 'uni' 0)
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks! I am going to try.